# Is there any logic like JUMP or GOTO I can use in Web.config for a VS-2015 web app

Tags: visual-studio

I have inherited the existing web app.  Mgmt only wants one version for both test and production.  The test-SQL site is commented out for production publishing, and the production-sql site if commented out  for test publishing.  It would be easier to set a variable as test or prod then jump over the affected lines in the appSettings in the web.config.  I do not see/find any real logic I can use.  Any ideas ?

Thanx

Comment: Well...now I see it is an XML document...my options dwindle.  I will see what I can do.   Sorry about the post. - Thanx

Answer (score 0):

What about just having the appSetting value="" as either test or live, thenthere's no jumping over the config.

But if you really have to jump around in the config, given that its been inherited, you could [and this really sucks by the way and should be avoided if at all possibe] perform an XSLT transformation on some XML (e.g. web.config, or a variant thereof such as web.config.xml). The XSLT can contain an XSL:IF condition and spit out an as-desired web.config.

Not sure if Visual Studio, or more accurately the compiler of your .Sln, will play nicely with this approach. If not you could potentially have the XSL transformation as part of your build process, that replaces / updates your web.config at build time. Like I say though, this approach sucks big time - it hardly follows the K.I.S principle, more the K.I.S.S principle.